# Finding a proper subgroup of $(\mathbb{R} \setminus \left\{0\right\}, \cdot)$

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, group-theory

> $(\mathbb{R} \setminus \left\{0\right\}, \cdot)$ is a group. Find a
>   real subset $U \varsubsetneqq  \mathbb{R} \setminus \left\{0\right\}$ such
>   that $(U, \cdot)$ is a subgroup of $(\mathbb{R} \setminus
> \left\{0\right\}, \cdot)$

This is a task from a test exam you can find here (in German): http://docdro.id/YncVusx

So this is really no homework and I'm looking for an explaining solution (please not too complicated).

---

So $(\mathbb{R} \setminus \left\{0\right\}, \cdot)$ is a group. Let its set be $S= \left\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\right\}$

Let the subset of $S$ be $U= \left\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\right\}$

Now, $(U, \cdot)$ is a subgroup of the group $(\mathbb{R} \setminus \left\{0\right\}, \cdot)$, if and only if $(U, \cdot)$ is a group.

$U$ is a group because it satisfies all axioms of a group, so it's a subgroup of the group $(\mathbb{R} \setminus \left\{0\right\}, \cdot)$?

This sounds so daft, I have no idea hot to solve tasks like this one >.<

Comment: So if $U$ is a group then you should be able to take two elements of $U$, lets say $4$ and $5$, and you should be able to find their product $4 \cdot 5$ in $U$. Which element of $U$ is equal to $4 \cdot 5$?

Comment: @LeeMosher None..? :P

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about just using $U = \{-1, 1\}$ $\subset$ $\mathbb{R}$ $\setminus$ $\{0\}$?

Retaining the binary operation of multiplication, does this example satisfy the group axioms?

(In fact: What about just using $\{1\}$ to form a subgroup?)

Answer (score 1):

$\{1 \}$ would work. Or $\{ - 1, 1 \}$. Or nonzero rational numbers. Or positive nonzero rational numbers. Or $\{ n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1} \} \cup \{ 1/n : n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1} \}$. These are all groups under the binary operation on $\mathbb{R} - \{ 0 \}$.

All we're looking for is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which is closed under multiplication, taking multiplicative inverses, not containing $0$, and containing $1$.

Answer (score 1):

A good method for finding nontrivial, proper subgroups of (almost) *any* group is to take all powers (if the group operation is multiplication/composition, and multiples if the operation is addition) of a given element.

So, if $G$ is the multiplicative group of nonzero real numbers, pick any nonidentity element of $G$; let's pick $2$.

Then the subset $H = \{2^k: k \in \Bbb Z\} \subset G$ of every integer power of $2$ is in fact a subgroup of $G$: It's closed under inverses (if $2^k \in H$, then $2^{-k} \in H$), and also multiplication  (given $2^{i}, 2^{j} \in H$, then $2^i \cdot 2^j = 2^{i + j} \in H$).

This is known as the subgroup *generated by* $2$, and often denoted $\langle 2 \rangle$.

Comment: This method gives two of the examples already given; $\langle 1 \rangle = \{1\}$ and $\langle -1 \rangle = \{\pm 1\}$.